# setAttributeNS doesnt work on method call - reactjs

Tags: javascript, events, dom, reactjs

I have a svg element `<svg id="svgMenuOpen" className="bottomMenu" width={302} height={302} onMouseDown={this.selectElement.bind(this)} >`. Methods -

```
selectElement(e){
    let svg = document.getElementById('svgMenuOpen');
    svg.setAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove", "this.moveElement");
}

moveElement(e){
    console.log('something')
}
```

`this.moveElement` is method, where i am just writing something to console for now . But this method isn't invoked. I tried instead of `this.moveElement` write `this.moveElement.bind(this)` or `this.moveElement()`, but it throw errors 
`this.moveElement is not a function` or `Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`. With `this.moveElement` there is no errors in console... when i simply write instead of `this.moveElement` just `console.log('something')`, it works. So any tips ?

Answer (score 0):

```
selectElement(e){
    let svg = document.getElementById('svgMenuOpen');
    const thiz = this;
    svg.onmousemove = function() {
      thiz.moveElement.bind(thiz);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is same problem, still without console log message, but again, when i write instead of `thiz.moveElement.bind(thiz);` just `console.log('some')` it works

Comment: you may need to force the component to re-render. can you check the onmousemove attribute of the corresponding element from the console ?

Comment: onmousemove works fine, during mouse moving, i am getting console input : some, so there is only problem with method calling. What can re-render solve  ?